# Prevent 413 error request entity too large in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a multipart file upload, and when I select more than 1 file I am getting a 413 error from my server.

How can I prevent the server throwing this error and increase the maximum request size?

I tried editing a `web.config` file in the root of my project

```
<system.web>
   <!-- maxRequestLength for asp.net, in KB --> 
   <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="10485760" ></httpRuntime> 
</system.web>

<system.webServer>              
   <security> 
      <requestFiltering> 
         <!-- maxAllowedContentLength, for IIS, in bytes --> 
         <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="10737418240" ></requestLimits>
      </requestFiltering> 
   </security>
</system.webServer>
```

but that didn't do anything

Answer (score -1):

You can try to increase the file size limit in machine config of the server

Comment: How? I tried adding some lines into a `web.config` file in the root of my project, but it didn't work.